# Can I tune my Brave browser for GPU-heavy HTML5 any more?

Tags: gpu, gaming, html5, performance-tuning, brave

How may I further increase performance of Chromium-based browsers (like Brave I currently use) for *heavy* HTML5 gaming. Let me define heavy as basically most of the day I run the game together with tons of other things. Please focus on the browser.

I work on Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon with a Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7577, let me name key components for this question descending on what I think could cause performance issues:

- a) **RAM**: 32GB DDR4 2400MHz dual-channel;
- b) **SSD**: M.2 PCIe NVMe Toshiba 512GB with OS Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon kernel 5.4.0-100-generic;
- c) **GPU**: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design 6GB GDDR5;
- d) **CPU**: Intel Core i7-7700HQ 2.8GHz base, TurboBoost up to 3.8GHz, HyperThreading enabled;
- e) **Display**: 3840 x 2160 (UHD 4K) 15.6" IPS.

---

e) From the bottom of my list, I am basically saying, I am sure the 4K display is the cause for overheating, somewhat slower response time, and generally wasting electric energy. But I love it, would not change it for anything.

d) CPU is not one of the fastest, I know, which is why I put it right above the display. Generally doing Ok. I already offloaded a lot of the browser work to GPU, which is why CPU is not my limiting factor I think.

c) GPU is doing fine, but I am thinking like - "Can I tune my Brave browser for GPU-heavy HTML5 any more?"

b) + a) There is so much of RAM and quite good SSD, I highly doubt these would cause any delays or generally hinder performance.

As a side note I do have Windows too, but I rarely use it. Linux is my work environment and I need to be in there.

---

### Currently applied tweaks on my Brave version 98.1.35.103:

- #enable-gpu-rasterization
- #enable-zero-copy
- #enable-drdc
- #canvas-oop-rasterization

### Current status of GPU:

Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Enabled
Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
OpenGL: Enabled
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated on all pages
Raw Draw: Disabled
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated

---

Question is: "Can I tune my Brave browser for GPU-heavy HTML5 any more?"

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you intentionally disable Vulkan or are you unable to enable it?

Comment: @Mokubai I tried to enable it, and it did not go well, unsure what happened.